# Make jump to bracket and select to bracket in VSCode stay within brackets (like Sublime)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to switch from Sublime Text to VSCode and two commands I'm quite dependent on are jumping and selecting between brackets which seem to differ between in VSCode compared to Sublime.

I've found an option in VSCode to do this, namely `editor.action.jumpToBracket` and `editor.action.selectToBracket`. The problem is that these differ to the ones in Sublime.

Jumping between brackets in Sublime stays within brackets and selecting does not include brackets, while in VSCode jumping moves outside of the brackets and selecting also includes brackets.

I would like to preserve the Sublime functionality. Is there a simple way to do that in VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the selection you can use the extensions

- [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)
- [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Add the following key binding

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+s",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.selectToBracket",
            { "command": "selectby.moveLastSelectionActive", "args": {"offset": -2} },
            { "command": "selectby.moveLastSelection", "args": {"offset": 1} }
        ]
    }
  }
```

It only works for a single selection.

I will add commands `selectby.moveSelectionActive` and `selectby.moveSelection` that will act on all selections.

The brackets is a bit more difficult because jump-to-bracket places the cursor before the bracket, but you have no idea if you jump to the open-bracket. If you have multiple brackets it is even harder: `((()()(())))`

---

**Edit**

With v1.17.0 of **Select By** it operates on all selections.

Modify to:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+s",  // or any other combo
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
        "sequence": [
            "editor.action.selectToBracket",
            { "command": "selectby.moveSelections", "args": {"start": 1, "end": -1} }
        ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @tepsijash modified the answer so it now works on all selections

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thank you so much. Will give it a try now :)

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer works, I've also submitted a bug request to VSCode which is accepted to be added to the backlog [[link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167686)]. In the meantime I've also found a way to only select within brackets. The detailed solution can be found in the link, but the gist is to create a custom keybinding with an extra argument, something like:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+m",
    "command": "editor.action.selectToBracket",
    "args": {
        "selectBrackets": false
    }
}
```